# Unity's SpeedTree leaves not showing on mobile devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need a help. There is a strange behavior of the SpeedTrees in a game.
As you can see on the following screenshot, the leaves of the trees are not showing.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT5FA.png

Notice that the billboards work properly, only the LODs have some issues. Moreover, the problem is caused not on all the devices: it displays tree leaves correctly on Macbook Air, Meizu MX4, Asus ZenPhone 6, but not on Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900F, Android 5.0).

The SpeedTree is standard without any changes, the graphics & quality settings are standard too.

Some specifications:

- The version of Unity: 5.1;
- The version of Android SDK: 23.0.2.

Thank you!

Comment: What texture compression mode are you using on the leave texture?

Comment: It is standard ETC1/RGBA for Android. No individual overrides for textures

Answer (score 0):

Found a reason of such a strange behavior of the SpeedTree - the WindZone object. After disabling it, everything displays properly.